# Replace row in excel based on specific value

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA and i got this difficult question.
I am using a sheet where i enter the cells and press a button to either make a new row or make a change to that row in the overview sheet.

The last one, i can not seem to get working.
I want the macro to check if the ID is present in the overview sheet.

Example

I got one record with ID 5000 and name "Luke"
And one record wtith ID 5001 and name "Cage"

I change the name in the the record with ID 5000 to "Xander" in my form sheet

I press the button "Change record" and the macro searches for the record with ID 5000 and changes the name into "Xander"

Hope you guys can help or point me in the right direction.

I found a way to do it, by first deleting and then adding it again.

```
    Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim Ticketnumber As Long

Sheets("Form").Select

Ticketnumber = Range("B1")

Sheets("Tickets").Select

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(iCntr, 1) = Ticketnumber Then
Rows(iCntr).Delete
End If
Next

Sheets("Form").Select

    Range("B1:B14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Tickets").Select
    Worksheets("Tickets").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Worksheets("Form").Range("B1:B14").Clear
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you show us the code you have written we are more likely to be effective in helping you.

Comment: i already found a way to do it. first i delete the entry and i add it

Comment: Without deleting, you can match() your value, determine cell row/column of the matched cell, in cells(row,column+1) you would insert the .value of your initial cell.  If you loop this through the list of cells, it would be relatively quick and doesn't require deleting/adding.  I will type this up in a little bit, if this is wanted.  Leaving a comment before dedicating effort, in case you don't need this.

Comment: @JeffBoud better to answer your own question than to edit a question to include the answerstackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Eh, thought about it and didn't have to write much.  Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tickets()

Dim i As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim IDN As Variant
Dim IDV As Variant
Dim IDNR As Integer
Dim IDNC As Integer

LR = Cells(Sheets("Overview").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
IDNR = ActiveCell.Row
IDNC = ActiveCell.Column

IDN = Cells(IDNR, IDNC).Value 'ID Name, you should highlight this cell when starting work
IDV = Cells(IDNR, IDNC - 1).Value 'ID Value, e.g. your ID 5001, if it is the adjacent cell left

If IDN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LR, 2)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(IDV, Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, 1)))).Value Then
    MsgBox "This matches!"

    Else:
        For i = 1 To LR
            If IDV = Sheets("Overview").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                Sheets("Overview").Cells(i, 2).Value = IDN
                Else:
                End If
                Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

I have some specific sheet names utilized, so watch that ("Overview" because you talked about that in your narrative) and the ActiveCell should be the cell with the name you're looking to verify (Cells (1,1) reads "ID 5001" and Cells(1,2) reads "Cage").

This will check through the list on Overview if "ID 5001" exists (matches your existing ID (adjacent to IDN) and would determine if the Name ("Cage") is in the adjacent cell.  If not, it will replace Cage with your prefered Name for that ID.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.